# How to Force Theme in Windows Runtime App

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'd like to ensure that my Windows Phone Runtime app (soon to be Universal app) always uses the dark theme. I've noticed that resources such as the background image on a default Hub app template automatically detect which theme is being used. In this, I'd like to ensure that my other resources and general look and feel of the app remains in the dark theme for the user's benefit.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will set you on the right path.

[Application.RequestedTheme MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme)

---

Then in your App.xaml

```XAML
<Application RequestedTheme="Dark">
```

You can even set it per page as well

```XAML
<Page x:Name="page"  RequestedTheme="Dark">
```

Comment: I will try this. On a side note, which is the purpose of my question in the first place, I've noticed that when I install my test Windows Phone runtime app on my device while in dark theme and then switch my device to light theme and go back to the app, the background does not change but the font foreground does? I have to completely restart my device for the themes to properly change. Is this a known bug?

Comment: That sounds like the app uses a StaticResource for the background rather than a ThemeResource. Only the later update live. Hard coding the background isn't a fix s the ASP will break in high contrast modes